# Comparing two tables. Want to return a flag

Tags: sql, sql-server

My database has many tables with many relationships among them. But this question pertains to three tables in particular.

I have books in my library under the table `"CATALOGUE"` and books reserved by members(many-to-many relationship) as another table `"RESERVATIONS"`, and borrowed books(many-to-many relationship) as another table `"BORROWED_BOOKS"`.

Basically, I have to output all details about books currently in reservations(which means I need to pull data from LIBRARY_BOOKS), as well as the members that have them reserved(data from LIBRARY_MEMBERS) and I also need to list out whether the book is currently on loan or not.

It is the last criteria which I'm having trouble with. I know that to find out whether a reserved book is currently on loan or not, I have to compare it against the `BORROWED_BOOKS` table but I don't know how to go about it to actually output it.

This is my incomplete code:

```
SELECT 
    M.Member_ID, 
    M.Name_U,
    R.Book_ID,
    C.ISBN,
    C.Title,
    C.Description_B,
    R.Reservation_date
    SOMETHING AS 'Loan Status'
FROM 
    dbo.Reservations R 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Library_Members M ON R.Member_ID = M.Member_ID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.[Library_Books] B ON R.Book_ID = B.Book_ID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Catalogue C ON C.ISBN = B.ISBN
ORDER BY M.Member_ID ASC
```

I need help at the last line of `SELECT`. How do I successfully compare the two tables `RESERVATIONS` and `BORROWED_BOOKS`, and return some kind of flag(?) which I can then output to indicate whether it is currently reserved or not? And also, how would I structure the `JOIN`of that particular comparison?

The columns in common between `RESERVATIONS` and `BORROWED_BOOKS` are: Book_ID. It's not a relationship, it's just that they both share this column.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can `EXISTS`

```
EXISTS( SELECT * FROM BORROWED_BOOKS WHERE Book_ID = R.Book_ID)
```

example

```
SELECT 
    M.Member_ID, 
    M.Name_U,
    R.Book_ID,
    C.ISBN,
    C.Title,
    C.Description_B,
    R.Reservation_date,
    EXISTS( SELECT * FROM BORROWED_BOOKS WHERE Book_ID = R.Book_ID) as reserved,
    SOMETHING AS 'Loan Status'
FROM 
    dbo.Reservations R 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Library_Members M ON R.Member_ID = M.Member_ID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.[Library_Books] B ON R.Book_ID = B.Book_ID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Catalogue C ON C.ISBN = B.ISBN
ORDER BY M.Member_ID ASC
```

Comment: Okay this means that if there's a matching Book_ID in both tables, it returns the word 'reserved'. How do I add the ELSE condition? Or do I need another statement that is identical except I use !=?

Comment: You can't write a bare `EXISTS` in a position where a non-predicate expression is expected. (At least in  [tag:sql-server], which is how this question is tagged)